# recursive php mysql huge query in a tree structure

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, nested, hierarchical-data

I have mysql query that gets all the parent ids to child map into an array, then i have a function to print out all child ids for a parent id.

what i want to accomplish now is get the username for each echoed child id using this function.
and paginate the result on each page if possible.

the mysql query + function to get the ids to childs map into array:

```
$res = $db->query('SELECT p.id AS parent, GROUP_CONCAT( c.id ) AS children
 FROM rev_r_clients AS p
 JOIN rev_r_clients AS c ON c.parent_client_id = p.id
 GROUP BY p.id');

 $parents = Array();
 while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
 $parents[$row['parent']] = explode(',',$row['children']);
}
```

Now the Function that print out the children for a specific parent ID:

```
function subtree($id, $parents) { 
 echo $id;
 echo ' <br> ';
 if (isset($parents[$id]))
 foreach ($parents[$id] as $child) 
{
 subtree($child, $parents);
}
```

Now any idea how to get the username from another MYSQL table ( rev_users ) 
and if possible paginate the result on each page?

Can't make a query for each row as the result is huge , thousand of child ids for each parent id.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query to return all the fields you need. Execute a new query for each row of the cursor is not a solution, but a workaround.

Comment: i have thousands of child ids for most parent id, query each row will make things crazy :D

Comment: Yes, it is my point. So, create JOIN to have only 1 query with all the fields you need for the render.

Comment: how is that? can you write example? i need the username field in the rev_users table then to be printed with the echoed child id